# place elements with multiple styles overlap

Tags: html, css, wordpress, bootstrap-4

I need help placing my items. I'm just starting out so I need explanations. What will seem obvious to you, will not necessarily be so for me :) I have a header that I want to improve.
I would like the two images on the right to be superimposed, ie the "reserve" button is above the image.
On the other hand, I would like to get to center the middle image.
I know the styles are overlapping and the changes I tried through the chrome console are not working. I can't impose the style I want and I can't necessarily find the style that blocks me.
If it's possible for you to give me some advice that would be great. Thank you.

The link is : https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/

HEADER

[image: HEADER]

```
<div class="site-branding">
    <div class="logo-main" style="text-align:left;" >
        <h1 class="site-title semantic">Hotel LOGIS LA BORIE en Périgord Noir</h1>          
            <a href="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/" rel="home" class="site-logo"><img id="desktop-logo" src="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Transparent.png" alt="Hotel LOGIS LA BORIE en Périgord noir" width="988" height="614">
                <img id="retina-logo" src="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Transparent.png" alt="Hotel LOGIS LA BORIE en Périgord noir" width="988" height="614">
            </a>
    <div class="tel-header" >Tel. +33 (0 53 28 97 60</div>
                </div>              
                    <div class="form-reservation">
                        <div class="logo-logis" >
                            <a href="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/sejoursur-logis.mp4" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                                <img src="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/BANDEAU-MAIL-400X100px-SEJOUR-PLUS-SUR-1.jpg" alt="lien de réservation" style="width: 400px !important;">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="group-input" >  
                            <div class="logo-logis" >
                                <a href="https://www.logishotels.com/fr/hotel/-254254?partid=568&amp;layout=search&amp;ref=r" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                                    <img style="width: 105px !important;" src="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/reservez-1.png" alt="lien de réservation" width="112" height="25"></a>
                                        <a href="https://www.logishotels.com/fr/hotel/hotel-la-borie-254254?PARTID=1012&amp;gclid=Cj0KCQjwvLLZBRDrARIsADU6ojBX_SZoGK4q8u1U_o9D7ym88hIxs1SkPMDf8VeswMveqWXBDF70HFsaApIXEALw_wcB" target="_blank">
                                            <img style="width: 105px !important;" src="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/themes/morrison-hotel/images/log-logis.png"></a>
                            </div>  
                         </div>     
                    </div>  
                </div>
```

If I add**transform: translateX(calc(100% + 10px))** to the "reservez" button it gives me :

[image]

I wanted to use the div containing both images and links as you can see on my code and put display : block but it doesn"t work to have it one above the other... The images are included in a link so if I change only the style of the img the  stays at his place.

Comment: Hi Onyssius! It would be helpful to share the code in order for everyone to be able to help you out

Comment: Alright, I'm sorry, I didn't because I thought It would me more helpful for helpers to have the link. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score -1):

you could translate the image by using css

```
img{
  transform: translateX(calc(100% + 10px))
}
```

the code move the image to right by 100% + 10px for example

or try to put the two images in the same tag then add to the top reservez button:

```
bottom:0
z-index:1
```

this will put it on the bottom and front

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer and help me ! When I do add "transform: translateX(calc(100% + 10px))" to "reservez" button  the button is just above the "logis" image at the bottom. I'm editing my post so you can see :)

Comment: simple just add top:0 instead of bottom:0

Answer (score -1):

sorry, i should explain better, here is an example of what im saying

```html
<div class="site-branding">
    <div class="logo-main" style="text-align:left;" >
        <h1 class="site-title semantic">Hotel LOGIS LA BORIE en Périgord Noir</h1>          
            <a href="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/" rel="home" class="site-logo"><img id="desktop-logo" src="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Transparent.png" alt="Hotel LOGIS LA BORIE en Périgord noir" width="988" height="614">
                <img id="retina-logo" src="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Transparent.png" alt="Hotel LOGIS LA BORIE en Périgord noir" width="988" height="614">
            </a>
    <div class="tel-header" >Tel. +33 (0 53 28 97 60</div>
                </div>              
                    <div class="form-reservation">
                        <div class="logo-logis" >
                            <a href="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/sejoursur-logis.mp4" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                                <img src="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/BANDEAU-MAIL-400X100px-SEJOUR-PLUS-SUR-1.jpg" alt="lien de réservation" style="width: 400px !important;">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="group-input" >  
                            <div class="logo-logis" style="position:relative;height:120px">
                                <a href="https://www.logishotels.com/fr/hotel/-254254?partid=568&amp;layout=search&amp;ref=r" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" style="position:absolute;bottom:0;left:0;z-index:1">
                                    <img style="width: 105px !important;" src="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/reservez-1.png" alt="lien de réservation" width="112" height="25">
                                 </a>
                                 <a href="https://www.logishotels.com/fr/hotel/hotel-la-borie-254254?PARTID=1012&amp;gclid=Cj0KCQjwvLLZBRDrARIsADU6ojBX_SZoGK4q8u1U_o9D7ym88hIxs1SkPMDf8VeswMveqWXBDF70HFsaApIXEALw_wcB" target="_blank" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0">
                                    <img style="width: 105px !important;" src="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/themes/morrison-hotel/images/log-logis.png" >
                                </a>
                            </div>  
                         </div>     
                    </div>  
                </div>
```

Comment: try to play with values and adjust to what you want.

Comment: and sorry by my english

Comment: Your English is perfect mine is null !!! I was wrong in my explanations ... I would have liked the button above the image but in the up / down direction not superimposed I do not know how to explain it in English and therefore I was wrong in my explanations. ..